# How to Log Users Who click Hyperlink

Tags: user, hyperlink, logging, download, monitoring

I have a SharePoint page with several hyperlinks pointing to different document downloads. I would like to log information everytime someone clicks a hyperlink. More specifically, I would like to keep a log of which document is downloaded, the user's name and/or username, and information from their profile (ie: Department, phone number, etc). The solution must exist within the SharePoint site because I do not have access to the physical server or its server logs.

I am very new to SharePoint. I heard that you might could add Javascript to the page, but I have no idea what to add or even how to add it. Also, there may be a web-part that could do this functionality, but I haven't been successful in finding one. Does anybody know of anyway to do this? HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to track content within SharePoint itself, then SharePoint's own [Audit logs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA010100005.aspx) should solve that request.  They can track whenever any content in SharePoint is viewed, when and by whom.  The reports are also available directly from the web UI though they are not as user-friendly as they could be.

For tracking all clicks. you might want to look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509231/track-all-clicked-elements-using-javascript) for some ideas.

Comment: Can you point me to where the Audit Logs show where the content is "viewed, when and by whom"? I see that I can set an option that shows "Opening or Downloading Documents" but the log just shows what items were opened or viewed, not who opened or viewed them.

Comment: Click on the Report Data tab and you will see the User Id of the person who took the action

Comment: Ohh nice, I see that now. Great! Ok, so this seems to generate alot of logs that I really don't need. Do you know if it can be done on a per-page basis rather than per-site?

Comment: The auditing itself is per site collection but the reports have a basic filter of per list or per user but anything beyond that is left to the user to do in Excel.  However, SharePoint only keeps 60 days of audit data so don't worry about overflowing your database.  That is also important to know in case you wanted to keep a long-term historical record as you will have to either pull this data periodically or disable the Audit cleanup timer job (not recommended)

Comment: Will audit log also captures the number clicks for a webpart on a page?